# Mean free path and Scale height

Tags: atmosphere, temperature, altitude

**Banks and Kockarts, in *Aeronomy (Part B)***, has provided *an illustration of the vertical distribution of the mean free path of atomic hydrogen for several thermopause temperatures* (Fig. 16.3, p.84/362). I am working to understand the *mean free path of species* and its relation to the *scale height at the exobase* by solving the aforementioned Fig.16.3. The following is what I performed to achieve this.

For thermosphere, assuming for atomic hydrogen a number density (n) of 10<sup>8</sup> per cm<sup>3</sup>, and cross section ($\sigma$) of 2.8 $\times$ 10<sup>-15</sup> cm<sup>2</sup>, I could calculate a mean free path (mfp) of 14.86 km (mfp = $\frac{1}{\sqrt2. n. \sigma}$).

At the altitude of the thermopause of 500 km, I calculated the acceleration due to gravity as 8.43 m/s<sup>2</sup>. Then, for a thermospheric temperature of 2000 K, calculated the scale height (H = $\frac{kT}{mg}$) for the atomic hydrogen as $\approx$ 1961 km.

Now, how to calculate the altitude at which the *mean free path* is equal to the *atmospheric scale height*?

Kindly help to equate mfp and H to find the altitude. Also, help me to understand the concept I am missing here.